Ashton Kutcher lookalike gets his brother a job as a janitor
It was probably made within the last 5 years, I cant figure out for the life of me what it was called or where I saw it. But this was the plot/summary...
It's with a guy that looks a lot like Ashton Kutcher, he plays the role of like a snobby stuck up rich guy in a suit that works for a company.  He has a brother  and hires his brother to work at his company.  He gets his brother to make an office poll or something on how long he can last... I think he eventually makes his brother be a janitor but the movie ends when the brother sings at a talent show or something like that or maybe just sings just to sing and does real good  and the Ashton Kutcher look alike ends up being impressed with his little brother then.
Does any of this ring a bell?

It has a few details similar to the movie Step Brothers including a snobby brother in a suit and a redeeming musical number at the end.

You may be right, but not sure where you equate Will Ferrel to Ashton Kutcher? Or maybe you are equating John C. Reilly? ;-)

I'm not equating them. But enough of the details match for a guess. Besides, Adam Scott is the brother in this scenario who would be considered the Ashton look-alike. A bit of a stretch, but not as much as the two leads.

That was more "tongue-in-cheek" than anything. This answer is definitely better than mine ...

I thought it was a joke, that's why I put "I'm" in italic. To alleviate blame. :) Still, never can tell with text...

Transferring or relating intonations through type is distinctly difficult. I get myself in trouble with this quite often, lol ...
